# Which MySQL query will have faster retrieval?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Say I have two tables. One, lets call it **typeDB**, has for rows consisting of an index, a type name, and a list of IDs for elements in the other table which are of this type. To get the rows from the second table - lets call it **dataDB** - of type 0, I could then basically do (in sloppy pseudocode):

```
$list = SELECT list FROM typeDB WHERE index=0
```

And then I could get the rows from dataDB using:

```
$array = explode($list)  
for (every element of list $i)  
    $results = SELECT * FROM dataDB WHERE index=$array[$i]
```

So my question is... is this any faster than just having a type field in dataDB, and then doing:

```
$results = SELECT * FROM dataDB WHERE type=$type
```

My thought was that because the first method didn't have to go through the entire database, it would be faster. But I don't really know how the database queries work. Which way do you think would be the most efficient? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put an index on the type column and use your second version, it will be much faster.
Also note that I think you are bit confused by what a database is.. A database is a collection of tables (as well as triggers, stored procedures, views, etc) so naming tables with the name somethingDB is a bit confusing.. 
When I say index i'm referring to a database index (nothing to do with what looks like a column you had called index).

to create the column and index you use something like this (for mysql)

```
ALTER TABLE dataDB ADD COLUMN `type` varchar(64)
CREATE INDEX type_index ON dataDB(type)
```

similar for other DBMS's

As brought up in the comments, you then need to join on the type column.
You can either have a table that has types and an auto increment id and a unique constraint on the type/name field.. Then use the auto increment id as the foreign key, or just make a type table with one column (type) which is the primary key. Either way will work and both have benefits (I would go with an auto increment column as I believe it is more flexible to work with in code).

If you did go with an auto increment column you'd have this:

```
CREATE TABLE dataType (
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE
)



ALTER TABLE dataDB ADD COLUMN `type` INT;
ALTER TABLE dataDB ADD CONSTRAINT fk_type FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES dataType(id);
```

then when you go to query dataDB if you want the type names (as opposed to the integers) you would do a join like this:

```
SELECT dataDB.list, dataType.name FROM dataDB 
INNER JOIN dataType ON dataDB.type=dataType.id 
where dataDB.type="$type"
```

This assumes types are some kind of name and not integers to begin with though, if they were integers all along just make the int value the only column of the dataType table and thus it would be your primary key.

Comment: that depends on how many different types there are. if he just got 5 types for 100 data tuples, an index won't ever be used because it only got a selectivity of <20%. but i agree with your answer. use the 2nd version and join the typeDB table.

Comment: I would make one change though, in that I'd include the `dataDB.type="$type"` within the `datatType ON` specification to limit the rows joined, as at present you will join all rows from `dataType` onto `dataDB` even when only a subset of `dataType` is requested.  Not a consideration for small tables, but good practise for when the table grows.

Comment: hmm interesting catch. I never really understood what the difference was between putting extra conditions in the ON clause verses the WHERE clause.